simple pybind11 wrapper in Yocto
I can build example.so and put it into /usr/lib in Yocto dunfell after I read https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1330.
This is example.cpp that includes pybind11 wrapper
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

    m.def("add", &add, "A function that adds two numbers");
}

Here is CMakeLists.txt to build example.cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.1)
project(example LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")

include(GNUInstallDirs)

find_path(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES Python.h
    PATH_SUFFIXES python3.8
    DOC "Path to Python header files"
)

message(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR: ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR})
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX ".so")
# PROJECT_NAME must be the same as the one in PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) 
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED example.cpp)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR})
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})


I have two questions:

I used find_path to find /usr/include/python3.8. Is there any better any?
Is there way to find the target's PYTHON_MODULE_EXTENSION? I want to put it into CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX.
I tried this:

execute_process(
    COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('EXT_SUFFIX'))"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTHON_MODULE_EXTENSION
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

But it found the local information.
This is the recipe:
SRC_URI = "git://git@...;protocol=ssh;branch=master"

PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "..."

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit cmake

DEPENDS = "python3 python3-pybind11"

FILES:${PN} = "/usr/lib/*.so"
FILES:${PN}-dev = ""


I think you can do the following for finding python programmatically in cmake like this
find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)

message("Python include dirs: ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

If you are using conda or a virtual python environment make sure it is activated when you run this else it will find the first occurrence in your $PATH variable.
I am not sure about module extension but you can find the python extension which is also automatically populated by find_package
message("Python extension: ${Python_EXTENSION_SUFFIX}")

